# Integrate $f(x)=\dfrac{x-1}{x^2+1}$

Tags: integration

I was working myself through old exams and stumbled across the following task:

> Calculate $$\int_1^3{\dfrac{x-1}{x^2+1}dx}$$

At first I thought that I could substitute something but I really don't get this to work.

I would be very happy if someone could help me with this one.

Greetings, Finn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\displaystyle \int{\dfrac{x-1}{x^2+1}dx}=\int{\dfrac{x}{x^2+1}dx}-\int{\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}dx}=\ln(x^2+1)/2-\arctan(x)$$

Comment: Oh thank you! I was thinking to complicated...

Comment: You are welcome Finn. Yes, we all sometimes overthink. :D

Comment: I agree, it should be $-arctan(x)$. But still, thank you for your solution :)

Comment: I was typing too fast, yes you are right @Mattos, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

split your integral into $$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{2x}{x^2+1}dx-\int\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider two integrals $\int \frac{x}{x^2+1   }dx$ and $\int \frac{1}{x^2+1}dx$

Answer (score 0):

Compute $$\left(\frac12\ln(x^2+1)-\arctan x\right)'$$